# Not getting expected result from sql query to find max value

Tags: sql

I am trying to get max value from a table but it's not giving me the correct value (max value).

I used this query to get value

```
SELECT MAX(column_name1) FROM table_name WHERE column_name2 = 'some_value'
```

The data type of column_name is VARCHAR. Is this the problem for showing this unexpected result ?

Comment: The result will always be the same value because you're defining a `WHERE` condition on it!

Comment: Show some data! If you're storing **numbers** in a `varchar` column, you might get unexpected results, since the `MAX()` will apply to the **alphabetical** ordering - not any numerical values.....

Comment: Actually there are more records with the value "some_value" and I want to get the max value of other column from those records only. I made a correction in my question and you will come to know now. These both columns are different.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  The value would always be `'some_value'`.  If you want the `max()`, remove the `where` clause:

```
SELECT MAX(column_name)
FROM table_name;
```

The data type has nothing to do with the issue.

Then you would use:

```
SELECT MAX(salary)
FROM table_name
WHERE name = 'John';
```

EDIT:

If you store numbers and dates as character strings instead of using native SQL types, then you are bound to have problems.  MySQL does have easy conversion from strings to numbers, so you can try this:

```
SELECT MAX(salary + 0)
FROM table_name
WHERE name = 'John';
```

But the real solution is to fix the data types.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, but I want to fetch max value from that some_vale. for example, suppose there are four records with the name= "John"(here some_value)  . and each person has some salary . so I want to get that max salary value from those four records only.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to data type. So please change the data type to int or float and try once.

Answer (score 0):

MAX() function is used to be applied in integer value, not for varchar

Comment: can you give me some examples?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to cast that varchar into int and its working now. I changed the query like this -

**SELECT MAX(CAST(column_name1 AS Int)) FROM table_name WHERE column_name2 = 'some_value'**